# Google autocomplete dropdown position issue

Tags: css, angular, google-places-api

I'm using [NgxAutocomPlace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-autocom-place) module in my Angular App, the following module work with google autocomplete API by generating `.pac-container` in which it shows autocomplete results.

The issue is that on mobile the dropdown goes above instead of below of the input and it's unusable for the final user, it looks like this:

[image]

And here is how's my code looks like:

```
<div class="container-indirizzo mb-3">
  <label>Indirizzo di consegna</label>
  <div class="inside-indirizzo">
      <div class="indirizzo">
        <input
          *ngIf="addressOptions !== null"
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          required
          placeholder="es. Via Disraeli"
          formControlName="indirizzo"
          ngxAutocomPlace
          [options]="addressOptions"
          (selectedPlace)="addressChange($event)"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="civico" *ngIf="isCivico">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="nciv" placeholder="N°" autofocus />
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to set the position of that dropdown under the `<input>`?

EDIT 1:

The issue happens on scroll or in mobile devices as the virtual keyboard is up, so the problem is the position set to pac-container when is triggered

EDIT 2:

I'm trying to do something like this on Address change and on scroll but even this doesn't have any effect:

```
 const top = this.indirizzo.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().top ;
  const pacContainer = document.querySelector('.pac-container') as HTMLElement;
  if (pacContainer) {
    console.log(window.scrollY + top + 60);
    pacContainer.style.top = window.scrollY + top + 60;
  }
```

Where indirizzo is Div where input is placed.

EDIT 3:

the .pac-container is generated under `<body>` so i think by forcing it be rendered under `<div class="indirizzo">` will solve the issue...

EDIT 4:

**SOLVED** by setting top to pac-container to fixed position of X pixel from top of the screen to bottom of input, but still looking for a better solution.

(so as from top 0 to end of my input there are 465px i just set `.pac-container top: 465px`) but as on some screens that height could be lower (some mobile 450 some other 460 other 470) the dropdown is still drawn badly..

Comment: Generally, z-index should resolve your issue. Can you help us with your working code pen or snippet with CSS and Google API import?

Comment: @DhruviMakvana i'm unable to make a working example via stackblitz, actually there is no custom CSS i'm just using https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/ for styling and this library for autocomplete https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-autocom-place

Comment: @DhruviMakvana yet tryed with z-index it had no effect..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Angular material this will help

```
.pac-container {
    z-index: 100000;
}
```

If you are using Bootstrap, this will help you.

```
::ng-deep .pac-container {
  z-index: 100000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this when the elements have loaded could solve the problem.

```
const pacContainer = document.querySelector('.pac-container') as HTMLElement;
const body = document.body as HTMLElement;
const indirizzo = document.querySelector('.indirizzo') as HTMLElement;
const clone = pacContainer.cloneNode(true);
indirizzo.appendChild(clone);
body.removeChild(pacContainer);
```

`.pac-container` `CSS` should contain `position: relative`.

Comment: Should i place it inside input text `(change)` method as the `.pac-container` is generated when the text changes and if the input loses focus it removes it from body?

Comment: @IgorMytyuk it completely removes the element and re-create it? I thought that simply hiding the autocomplete container div would be enough. Check to see if you get any errors in console when the element is destroyed. In addition the above snippet should also be placed in a `onFocus` or `onChange` event.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced such issue with bootstrap and angular material ui.
With these 2 cases, I used the following css.

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/deep/ .pack-container{
  z-index: 10000 !important;
  position: fixed !important;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).